# How to use different columns for for loop iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, multiple-columns

So i want to do an iteration a vairable amount of times (a)

I have an excel sheet where that iteration is already programmed and i want to do the same now in python 3 spyder.[image]

I decided to calculate the first row externally. The iteration should now look like this:
da,air core diameter (2,1) is has the input t_new (1,5), delta p, spray pressure (2,2) has input da,air core diameter (2,1), t_new (2,5) has the input delta p, spray pressure (2,2) and so on for a given number of iterations.

My code looks as follows up until now (everything else is defined properly beforehand):

```
a = [b for b in range(14)]                                          # number of iterations -1
arr = np.array([[da_iter], [ps_iter], [t_mod_iter]]).reshape(1,3)   # external calculated values first row  
arr_zeros = np.zeros([len(a), 3])                                   # filling array with 0's based on iteration number

arr_iter = np.vstack((arr, arr_zeros))      #iteration array with 1st row calculated values

i = 0   #row index
j = 0   #column index

for i in range(len(arr_iter)):
    
    np.append(arr_iter, do_in-2*arr_iter[i,j+2])            #calculating new da out of t_mod
    np.append(arr_iter, ml**2*gs*0.5*pl*((dsc/(2*pl*(hsc*din*arr_iter[i+1,j]/2)))**2+(1/(pl*(ao-np.pi/4*arr_iter[i+1,j]**2)))**2))      #calculating new ps out of new da
    np.append(arr_iter, k*(1738.7*ul**2-79.898*ul+2.0122)*((do_in*ml*ul)/(pl*arr_iter[i+1,j+1]))**0.25)                 #calculation new t_new out of spray pressure
    
    i = i+1
print(arr_iter)
```

But that doesnt seem to work properly since i only get out arr_iter as it was before. Unfortunatley i also didnt found sth usefull how to iterate over changing rows using a for loop.

Does somebody have a better idea how to do it or sees my mistake in the loop?
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you don't need `i=i+1` as **for loop** already doing the same.

Secondly, I think you want to replace zeros in `arr_iter` so in for loop, you should write something like

```
np.append(arr_iter[i, j], 2nd_variable)
```

Alternatively you can simply do the following to update `arr_iter` matrix, rather than `append`.

```
arr_iter[i][j] = new_variable
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by 2nd_variable?

Comment: 2nd variable mean your new calculated variable. Line do_in-2*arr_iter[i,j+2] is new calculated variable.

Comment: **i, j** in `arr_iter[i, j]` are the position/location parameters in arr_iter matrix where you want to append the new element.